# Overriding properties & inheritance issue

Tags: inheritance, properties, d, overriding

I did no major changes to any of my modules, but suddenly it started to fail compiling a lot of my modules.

I get the following errors

```
borders.d(190): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
borders.d(191): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\image.d(117): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\image.d(121): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\image.d(121): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(45): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(59): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(73): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(89): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(100): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\imagebutton.d(110): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\labelbutton.d(78): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\labelbutton.d(89): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(245): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(247): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(259): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(309): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(310): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(324): Error: function aeri.context.Context.size (Point newSize) is not callable using argument types ()
controls\textbox.d(325): Error: function aeri.context.Context.position (Point newPosition) is not callable using argument types ()
```

Just to show an example of what causes it. Here is a code snippet from `borders.d`

```
this(Context parent, Paint topPaint, Paint rightPaint, Paint bottomPaint, Paint leftPaint) {
    super();

    if (!parent)
        throw new BorderException("Pass a context to render the border around.");

    m_parent = parent;
    m_topPaint = topPaint;
    m_rightPaint = rightPaint;
    m_bottomPaint = bottomPaint;
    m_leftPaint = leftPaint;

    position = parent.position; // Line 190
    size = parent.size; // Line 191
}
```

Now let's look at `Context.position` and `Context.size`

```
override void size(Point newSize) {
        super.size = newSize;

        if (m_backgroundPaint != transparent) {
            m_backgroundShape = new RectangleShape(Vector2f(cast(float)super.width, cast(float)super.height));
            m_backgroundShape.fillColor = m_backgroundPaint.toSfmlColor();
            m_backgroundShape.position = Vector2f(cast(float)super.x, cast(float)super.y);
        }
        if (m_border) {
            m_border.size = Point(super.size);
        }
    }

    override void position(Point newPosition) {
        super.position = newPosition;

        if (m_backgroundShape) {
            m_backgroundShape.position = Vector2f(cast(float)super.x, cast(float)super.y);
        }
        if (m_border) {
            m_border.position = Point(super.position);
        }
    }
```

Those are the setters.
`Context` inherits a class called `Space` which has getters / setters for position and size. `Context` only overrides the setters, but the getters are the same and should be called from `Space`. It seems like it doesn't even get the properties from `Space` at all. As you can see it tries to get the setters when it should get the getters. However all this code worked earlier.

Here are the properties in `Space`.

```
    Point position() { return m_position; }

    void position(Point newPos) {
        m_position = newPos;
    }

    Point size() { return m_size; }

    void size(Point newSize) {
        m_size = newSize;
    }
```

Note: I wrap all my properties like the following just in case you wonder why `@property` is not found.

```
@property {
    // properties
}
```

I really can't figure out what could be causing this and it leads me to think it has to do with the order the compiler is analyzing the modules?

I'm still trying to solve this myself, but I can't spot what's wrong and it all seemed to break after I changed some lines in `Space`, but none of its members.

In case you wonder the errors in `image.d`, `imagebutton.d`, `labelbutton.d` and `textbox.d` are caused by the same thing. They all inherit `Context` and overrides size / position too.
So the inheritance basically goes like this:

```
x (ex. Image, ImageButton, LabelButton, TextBox etc.)
----Control
--------Context
------------Space
```

`LabelButton` and `ImageButton` inherits `Button` which inherits `Control`.
`Control` does not override anything has any members from `Context`, so all calls to `Control` goes directly to `Context`. The same goes for `Button`, except for that it has some internal members for handling mouse events (which is handled in `Context`, but it calls that.)

Here are the `Control` class and `Button` class just in case.

```
class Control : Context {
protected:
    this(string name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

`...`

```
class Button : Control {
private:
    bool m_intersecting = false;
    bool m_focused = false;

    void handleMouseReleased(Context context, Mouse.Button button) {
        m_focused = m_intersecting;
        if (m_focused && button == Mouse.Button.Left) {
            foreach (event; m_onClick) {
                if (event)
                    event.exec();
            }
        }
    }

    void handleMouseMove(Context context, Point position){
        m_intersecting = super.intersect(position);
    }
protected:
    this(string name) {
        super(name);

        super.onMouseReleased(new MouseClickEvent(&handleMouseReleased));
        super.onMouseMove(new PositionEvent(&handleMouseMove));
    }

    private Action[] m_onClick;

    public void onClick(Action event) {
        if (!validMessageThread)
            throw new MessageException("Cannot register an event outside of the application thread / render thread");

        m_onClick ~= event;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information or code. However I think this should be enough. The inheritance and overriding of properties / property calls worked fine earlier.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but did you update to the new compiler? (dmd 2067.0).

If so, it may be worthwhile downgrading to 2066.1 to see if it fixes it.

Comment: If you are using `git`, you can use `git blame` to find the point at which the compilation started failing. It would be much easier to know and solve the problem if you can localize it to a small change.

Comment: Does it work if you add `@property` directly to the function declarations? You could try running DMD with `-property` which enforces `@property` for the `o.prop = x` syntax, maybe that will give a nicer message.

Comment: Also make sure those getters aren't private, I think there was a recent change about how private methods were looked up that might account for it.

Comment: My compiler is not the latest. In fact I haven't updated my compiler since last year. It all worked earlier and then suddenly this happened. I'm not using git either. Also compiling with -property didn't work either. Declaring @property manually didn't change anything either. At last they're all declared in a public scope within the class(es). I found out what causes it and it seems to be a compiler bug. Apparently it's because Context overrides position/size (only the setters) and then it never looks down in Space for the getters. If I comment out position/size in Context then it works.

Comment: Can someone clarify if it's a bug or normal behaviour? Typing out an answer as I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue and it seem to be a compiler bug (Or at least it doesn't seem to be a normal behaviour.)

I was overriding the setters for `position/size` from `Space` within `Context`, thus the compiler was never looking for the getters within `Space`, but in `Context`.

What I did to solve it was overriding the getters for `position/size` from `Space` within `Context`.

Comment: It is not a compiler bug. The spec says that when doing overload resolution, the functions in the base class are not considered. To consider them, you can use an alias as follows: `alias position = Space.position;`.
Source: http://dlang.org/function.html#function-inheritance

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification :) I think that's a strange behaviour to be honest but I guess there was a reason behind it :p